# JQuery - hide a button if no other button has the class that warrants it's appearance

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am having an issue with handling the control flow of the following process.

When you select P2, you are presented with a wheel of buttons. As soon as you click one button, the let's go button appears. When you deselect that button, it is still there.

I would like a solution that builds ontop of my code, where if there are no buttons that have the class 'actived', the let's go button doesn't appear.

Right now, if you select one it adds the class to make it appear, but deselecting it doesnt.

I have tried multi-selectors for logo1, logo2... and so on, to NOT have the class 'actived' and if there is no class of a logo with 'actived' the let's go button should not appear, but that hasn't worked.

Can you help me find a way to prevent the let's go button appearing if there is no logo button with the class of 'actived?' At least 1 button should be selected.

Thanks so much stack.

```js
$('.circle .semi-circle-1').on('click', function(){
    $('.circle .semi-circle-2').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#logo').addClass('pets');
    $('.pet').addClass('visualised');
    $('.instructions-arrow-1').addClass('hide');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').removeClass('hide');
    $('.petOwner').removeClass('visualised');
    $('.PTitle').addClass('actived');
    $('.POTitle').removeClass('actived');
    $('.div3').addClass('actived');
    $('.div2').removeClass('actived');
    $('.logo1').removeClass('active');
    $('#b1').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b1').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b1').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo2').removeClass('active');
    $('#b2').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b2').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b2').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo3').removeClass('active');
    $('#b3').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b3').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b3').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo4').removeClass('active');
    $('#b4').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b4').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b4').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo5').removeClass('active');
    $('#b5').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b5').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b5').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo6').removeClass('active');
    $('#b6').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b6').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b6').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo7').removeClass('active');
    $('#b7').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b7').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b7').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo8').removeClass('active');
    $('#b8').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b8').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b8').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo9').removeClass('active');
    $('#b9').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b9').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b9').addClass('dead');
    $('#popoutPets').addClass('expand');
    $('#popoutOwners').removeClass('expand');
    $('.animated-circle').addClass('hide');
    // $('.popout-instructions').addClass('hide');
    // $('.popout-petowner-splice').removeClass('show');
    // $('.popout-pet-splice').addClass('show');
    });

$('.circle .semi-circle-2').on('click', function(){
    $('.circle .semi-circle-1').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#logo').removeClass('pets');
    $('.instructions-arrow-1').addClass('hide');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').removeClass('hide');
    $('.petOwner').addClass('visualised');
    $('.pet').removeClass('visualised');
    $('.POTitle').addClass('actived');
    $('.PTitle').removeClass('actived');
    $('.div2').addClass('actived');
    $('.div3').removeClass('actived');
    $('.logo10').removeClass('active');
    $('#b10').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b10').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b10').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo11').removeClass('active');
    $('#b11').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b11').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b11').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo12').removeClass('active');
    $('#b12').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b12').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b12').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo13').removeClass('active');
    $('#b13').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b13').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b13').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo14').removeClass('active');
    $('#b14').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b14').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b14').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo15').removeClass('active');
    $('#b15').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b15').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b15').addClass('dead');
    $('#popoutOwners').addClass('expand');
    $('#popoutPets').removeClass('expand');
    $('.animated-circle').addClass('hide');
    // $('.popout-instructions').addClass('hide');
    // $('.popout-petowner-splice').addClass('show');
    // $('.popout-pet-splice').removeClass('show');
    });

    $('.tooltip').hover(function(){
      $('.description').addClass('show');
      $('.tooltip').addClass('hovered')
    },function(){
        $('.description').removeClass('show');
        $('.tooltip').removeClass('hovered');
    });
    

// Mini Buttons Toggle

$('.logo1').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo1').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b1').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b1').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b1').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo2').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo2').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b2').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b2').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b2').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')    
  });

  $('.logo3').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo3').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b3').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b3').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b3').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo4').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo4').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b4').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b4').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b4').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo5').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo5').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b5').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b5').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b5').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo6').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo6').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b6').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b6').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b6').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo7').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo7').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b7').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b7').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b7').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo8').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo8').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b8').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b8').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b8').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo9').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo9').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b9').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b9').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b9').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo10').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo10').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b10').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b10').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b10').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo11').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo11').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b11').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b11').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b11').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo12').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo12').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b12').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b12').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b12').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo13').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo13').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b13').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b13').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b13').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo14').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo14').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b14').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b14').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b14').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo15').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo15').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b15').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b15').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b15').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });
```

```css
.jonsIdea {
    position: relative;
    height: 105vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

#centre-circle {
    zoom: 0.95;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: visibility 0.25s, opacity 0.25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0.25s, opacity 0.25s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0.25s, opacity 0.25s linear;
}

.circle {
    width: 37vw;
    height: 85vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    position: flex;
    z-index: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top:3vw;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: visibility 0.2s, opacity 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0.2s, opacity 0.25s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0.2s, opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.semi-circle-1 {
    height: 11vw;
    width: 22vw;
    border-radius: 11vw 11vw 0 0;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color:#0000a0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.042vw;
    z-index: 2;
    position: inherit;
    display: inherit;
    max-width: 30vw;
    max-height: 15vw;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
}

.semi-circle-1:hover{
    z-index: 1000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.425vw 0.334vw #0505b3;
}

.semi-circle-2:hover{
    z-index: 1000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.425vw 0.334vw #ff1414;
}



.semi-circle-2.active {
    background-color: white!important;
    box-shadow: 0px -8px 1vw 0vw #ff1414;
    z-index: 3;
}

.semi-circle-1.active {
    background-color: white!important;
    box-shadow: 0px -8px 1vw 0vw #0505b3;
    z-index: 3;
}

.semi-circle-2 {
    height: 11vw;
    width: 22vw;
    border-radius: 11vw 11vw 0 0;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.042vw;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    position: inherit;
    display: inherit;
    max-width: 30vw;
    max-height: 15vw;
    align-items: center;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
}


#poj {
    position: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    margin: auto;
}

#pot{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 2.969vw;
    margin-top: -8vh;
}


.orbit {
    width: 27.3vw;
    height: 27.3vw;
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(90deg)
}


 .div2 {
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 2.083vw;
    height: 2.083vw;
    background-color: #ac5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .div2.actived{
    display: inherit;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .p1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23.317291666666666vw; 
    left: 25.3715625vw;
    }

   .p2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 29.01760416666667vw;
    left: 15.49828125vw;
    }

    .p3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 27.037916666666668vw; 
    left: 4.270833333333333vw;
    }

    .p4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 18.30447916666667vw;
    left: -3.057375vw;
    }

    .p5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6.903854166666666vw;
    left: -3.057375vw;
    }

    .p6 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.8295885416666668vw;
    left:4.270833333333333vw;
    }

    .p7 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3.809296875vw;
    left: 15.49828125vw;
    }

    .p8 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.8910416666666667vw;
    left: 25.3715625vw;
    }

    .p9 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.604166666666666vw;
    left: 29.270833333333332vw;
    }

    .p10 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 27.037916666666668vw;
    left: 20.9375vw;
    }

    .p11 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 27.037916666666668vw;
    left: 4.270833333333333vw;
    }

    .p12 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.604166666666666vw;
    left: -4.0625vw;
    }

    .p13 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.8295885416666668vw;
    left: 4.270833333333333vw;
    }

    .p14 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.8295885416666668vw;
    left: 20.9375vw;
    }

    .p15 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.604166666666666vw;
    left: 29.270833333333332vw;
    }


  .div3 {
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 2.083vw;
    height: 2.083vw;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .div3.actived{
    display: inherit;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .div4 {
    width: 2.083vw;
    height: 2.083vw;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%
  }

  #logo {
    position: block;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    left: -1.172vw;
    top: -1.094vw;
    width: 7vw;
    height: 7vw;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0.208vw solid red;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0#ff1414;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
  }

 


  #logo.active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.625vw 0.234vw #ff1414;
  }

.lg-circ{
    font-family: Zooja;
    color: white;
    font-size:24px;
    position: absolute;
}

.lg-circ p {
    margin-top: 2vh;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
}

#lets-go {
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#lets-go {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    align-self: center;
    line-height: 55px;
}
#lets-go.actived {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="jonsIdea" id='jonsIdea'>
        <div id="popoutLetsGo">
            <div class="lg-circ">
                <a id='lets-go'>Let's go!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <g id='centre-circle'>
            <div class="circle">
                <div class="semi-circle semi-circle-1" id='petsSemi1'>
                    <section id='pets-J'>
                        <p>P1</p>
                        <img id='pets-logo' src="/static/images/mars/Mars Petcare Compact Frieze RGB.svg" alt="">
                    </section>

                </div>
                <div class='breaker'> '</div>
                <div class="semi-circle semi-circle-2" id='petsSemi2'>
                    <section id='poj'>
                        <p id='pot'>P2</p>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="orbit" id='orbit'>
                    <div class="animated-circle"></div>
                    <div class="div2 p1">
                    <img title='Banfield' class='logo1' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/Mars Petcare product logo web Banfield large.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p2">
                    <img title='Blue Pearl' class='logo2' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/Mars petcare product logo Blue Pearl large.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p3">
                    <img title='Pet Partners' class='logo3' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/ppl.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p4">
                    <img title='Pet Nutrition' class='logo4' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/mpn.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p5">
                    <img title='Puppo' class='logo5' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/Mars Petcare product logo web puppo large.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p6">
                    <img title='Royal Canin' class='logo6' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/royal-canin-squarelogo-1538592764738.png" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p7">
                    <img title='VCA' class='logo7' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/Mars Petcare product logo web VCA large.png" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p8">
                    <img title='Whistle' class='logo8' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/Mars Petcare product logo web Whistle large.png" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p9" >
                    <img title='Wisdom' class='logo9' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/Wisdom Panel Logo.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider refactoring your code quite a bit, there is a lot of work done over and over.

I removed the `addClass("actived")` from all the click handlers, added the class `logo` to all logo-classes and added a handler which will be called after click on logo after your hander is being called.

You can pretty much do all the logo work in the new handler I wrote.

```js
$('.circle .semi-circle-1').on('click', function(){
    $('.circle .semi-circle-2').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#logo').addClass('pets');
    $('.pet').addClass('visualised');
    $('.instructions-arrow-1').addClass('hide');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').removeClass('hide');
    $('.petOwner').removeClass('visualised');
    $('.PTitle').addClass('actived');
    $('.POTitle').removeClass('actived');
    $('.div3').addClass('actived');
    $('.div2').removeClass('actived');
    $('.logo1').removeClass('active');
    $('#b1').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b1').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b1').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo2').removeClass('active');
    $('#b2').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b2').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b2').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo3').removeClass('active');
    $('#b3').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b3').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b3').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo4').removeClass('active');
    $('#b4').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b4').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b4').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo5').removeClass('active');
    $('#b5').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b5').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b5').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo6').removeClass('active');
    $('#b6').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b6').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b6').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo7').removeClass('active');
    $('#b7').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b7').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b7').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo8').removeClass('active');
    $('#b8').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b8').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b8').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo9').removeClass('active');
    $('#b9').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b9').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b9').addClass('dead');
    $('#popoutPets').addClass('expand');
    $('#popoutOwners').removeClass('expand');
    $('.animated-circle').addClass('hide');
    // $('.popout-instructions').addClass('hide');
    // $('.popout-petowner-splice').removeClass('show');
    // $('.popout-pet-splice').addClass('show');
    });

$('.circle .semi-circle-2').on('click', function(){
    $('.circle .semi-circle-1').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#logo').removeClass('pets');
    $('.instructions-arrow-1').addClass('hide');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').removeClass('hide');
    $('.petOwner').addClass('visualised');
    $('.pet').removeClass('visualised');
    $('.POTitle').addClass('actived');
    $('.PTitle').removeClass('actived');
    $('.div2').addClass('actived');
    $('.div3').removeClass('actived');
    $('.logo10').removeClass('active');
    $('#b10').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b10').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b10').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo11').removeClass('active');
    $('#b11').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b11').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b11').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo12').removeClass('active');
    $('#b12').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b12').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b12').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo13').removeClass('active');
    $('#b13').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b13').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b13').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo14').removeClass('active');
    $('#b14').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b14').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b14').addClass('dead')
    $('.logo15').removeClass('active');
    $('#b15').removeClass('alive');
    $('#b15').removeClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b15').addClass('dead');
    $('#popoutOwners').addClass('expand');
    $('#popoutPets').removeClass('expand');
    $('.animated-circle').addClass('hide');
    // $('.popout-instructions').addClass('hide');
    // $('.popout-petowner-splice').addClass('show');
    // $('.popout-pet-splice').removeClass('show');
    });

    $('.tooltip').hover(function(){
      $('.description').addClass('show');
      $('.tooltip').addClass('hovered')
    },function(){
        $('.description').removeClass('show');
        $('.tooltip').removeClass('hovered');
    });
    

// Mini Buttons Toggle

$('.logo1').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo1').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b1').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b1').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b1').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide');
  });

  $('.logo2').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo2').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b2').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b2').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b2').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide');
  });

  $('.logo3').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo3').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b3').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b3').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b3').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
  });

  $('.logo4').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo4').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b4').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b4').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b4').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide');
  });

  $('.logo5').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo5').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b5').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b5').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b5').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide');
  });

  $('.logo6').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo6').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b6').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b6').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b6').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide');
  });

  $('.logo7').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo7').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b7').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b7').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b7').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide');
  });

  $('.logo8').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo8').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b8').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b8').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b8').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide');
  });

  $('.logo9').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.logo9').toggleClass("active");
    $('#b9').toggleClass('alive');
    $('#b9').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
    $('#b9').toggleClass('dead');
    $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
    $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide');
  });
  
  $('.logo').on('click', function(e) {
    const hasActiveLogo = $('.logo.active').length > 0;
    
    if(hasActiveLogo) {
      $('#lets-go').addClass('actived');
    } else {
      $('#lets-go').removeClass('actived');
    }
  });
```

```css
.jonsIdea {
    position: relative;
    height: 105vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

#centre-circle {
    zoom: 0.95;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: visibility 0.25s, opacity 0.25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0.25s, opacity 0.25s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0.25s, opacity 0.25s linear;
}

.circle {
    width: 37vw;
    height: 85vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    position: flex;
    z-index: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top:3vw;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: visibility 0.2s, opacity 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0.2s, opacity 0.25s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0.2s, opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.semi-circle-1 {
    height: 11vw;
    width: 22vw;
    border-radius: 11vw 11vw 0 0;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color:#0000a0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.042vw;
    z-index: 2;
    position: inherit;
    display: inherit;
    max-width: 30vw;
    max-height: 15vw;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
}

.semi-circle-1:hover{
    z-index: 1000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.425vw 0.334vw #0505b3;
}

.semi-circle-2:hover{
    z-index: 1000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.425vw 0.334vw #ff1414;
}



.semi-circle-2.active {
    background-color: white!important;
    box-shadow: 0px -8px 1vw 0vw #ff1414;
    z-index: 3;
}

.semi-circle-1.active {
    background-color: white!important;
    box-shadow: 0px -8px 1vw 0vw #0505b3;
    z-index: 3;
}

.semi-circle-2 {
    height: 11vw;
    width: 22vw;
    border-radius: 11vw 11vw 0 0;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.042vw;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    position: inherit;
    display: inherit;
    max-width: 30vw;
    max-height: 15vw;
    align-items: center;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
}


#poj {
    position: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    margin: auto;
}

#pot{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 2.969vw;
    margin-top: -8vh;
}


.orbit {
    width: 27.3vw;
    height: 27.3vw;
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(90deg)
}


 .div2 {
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 2.083vw;
    height: 2.083vw;
    background-color: #ac5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .div2.actived{
    display: inherit;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .p1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23.317291666666666vw; 
    left: 25.3715625vw;
    }

   .p2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 29.01760416666667vw;
    left: 15.49828125vw;
    }

    .p3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 27.037916666666668vw; 
    left: 4.270833333333333vw;
    }

    .p4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 18.30447916666667vw;
    left: -3.057375vw;
    }

    .p5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6.903854166666666vw;
    left: -3.057375vw;
    }

    .p6 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.8295885416666668vw;
    left:4.270833333333333vw;
    }

    .p7 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3.809296875vw;
    left: 15.49828125vw;
    }

    .p8 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.8910416666666667vw;
    left: 25.3715625vw;
    }

    .p9 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.604166666666666vw;
    left: 29.270833333333332vw;
    }

    .p10 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 27.037916666666668vw;
    left: 20.9375vw;
    }

    .p11 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 27.037916666666668vw;
    left: 4.270833333333333vw;
    }

    .p12 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.604166666666666vw;
    left: -4.0625vw;
    }

    .p13 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.8295885416666668vw;
    left: 4.270833333333333vw;
    }

    .p14 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.8295885416666668vw;
    left: 20.9375vw;
    }

    .p15 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.604166666666666vw;
    left: 29.270833333333332vw;
    }


  .div3 {
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 2.083vw;
    height: 2.083vw;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .div3.actived{
    display: inherit;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .div4 {
    width: 2.083vw;
    height: 2.083vw;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%
  }

  #logo {
    position: block;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    left: -1.172vw;
    top: -1.094vw;
    width: 7vw;
    height: 7vw;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0.208vw solid red;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0#ff1414;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
  }

 


  #logo.active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.625vw 0.234vw #ff1414;
  }

.lg-circ{
    font-family: Zooja;
    color: white;
    font-size:24px;
    position: absolute;
}

.lg-circ p {
    margin-top: 2vh;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
}

#lets-go {
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#lets-go {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    align-self: center;
    line-height: 55px;
}
#lets-go.actived {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="jonsIdea" id='jonsIdea'>
        <div id="popoutLetsGo">
            <div class="lg-circ">
                <a id='lets-go'>Let's go!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <g id='centre-circle'>
            <div class="circle">
                <div class="semi-circle semi-circle-1" id='petsSemi1'>
                    <section id='pets-J'>
                        <p>P1</p>
                        <img id='pets-logo' src="/static/images/mars/Mars Petcare Compact Frieze RGB.svg" alt="">
                    </section>

                </div>
                <div class='breaker'> '</div>
                <div class="semi-circle semi-circle-2" id='petsSemi2'>
                    <section id='poj'>
                        <p id='pot'>P2</p>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="orbit" id='orbit'>
                    <div class="animated-circle"></div>
                    <div class="div2 p1">
                    <img title='Banfield' class='logo logo1' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/Mars Petcare product logo web Banfield large.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p2">
                    <img title='Blue Pearl' class='logo logo2' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/Mars petcare product logo Blue Pearl large.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p3">
                    <img title='Pet Partners' class='logo logo3' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/ppl.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p4">
                    <img title='Pet Nutrition' class='logo logo4' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/mpn.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p5">
                    <img title='Puppo' class='logo logo5' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/Mars Petcare product logo web puppo large.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p6">
                    <img title='Royal Canin' class='logo logo6' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/royal-canin-squarelogo-1538592764738.png" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p7">
                    <img title='VCA' class='logo logo7' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/Mars Petcare product logo web VCA large.png" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p8">
                    <img title='Whistle' class='logo logo8' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/Mars Petcare product logo web Whistle large.png" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                    <div class="div2 p9" >
                    <img title='Wisdom' class='logo logo9' id='logo' src="/static/images/businesses/Wisdom Panel Logo.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
```

Comment: Hi Pilan, thanks so much for your response. Is it safe to copy and paste this into my code?